# Is cache miss rate the only thing that matters when deciding which is better or performs better?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

If I have two different cache subsystem designs C1 and C2 that both have roughly the same hardware complexity, can I make a decision if which one is better choice considering effectiveness of cache subsystem is the prime factor i.e., the number misses should be minimized.

Give the total miss rate below:

`miss_rate = (number of cache misses)/(number of cache reference)`

- `miss rate of C1 = 0.77`
- `miss rate of C2 = 0.73`

Is the given miss rate information sufficient to make decision of what subsystem is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming hit latency is the same for both caches, actual miss rate on the workload you care about is the ultimate factor *for that workload*.  It doesn't always generalize.

All differences in size, associativity, eviction policy, all matter because of their impact on miss rate on any given workload.  Even cache line (block) size factors in to this: a cache with twice as many 32-byte lines vs. a cache with half as many 64-byte lines would be able to cache more scattered words, but pull in less nearby data on a miss.  (Unless you have hardware prefetching, but again prefetch algorithms ultimately just affect miss rate.)

If hit and miss latencies are fixed, then all misses are equal and you just want fewer of them.

Well, not just latency, but overall effect on the pipeline, if the CPU isn't a simple in-order design from the 1980s that simply stalls on a miss.  Which is what homework usually assumes, because otherwise the miss cost depends on details of the context, making it impossible to calculate performance based on just instruction mix, hit/miss rate, and miss costs.

An out-of-order exec CPU can hide the latency of some misses better than others.  (On the critical path of some larger dependency chain vs. not.)  Even an in-order CPU that can scoreboard loads can get work done in the shadow of a cache miss load, up until it reaches an instruction that reads the load result.  (And with a store buffer, can usually hide store miss latency.)  So miss penalty can differ depending on *which* loads miss, whether it's one that software instruction scheduling was able to hide more vs. less of the latency for.  (If the independent work after a load includes other loads, then you'd need a non-blocking cache that handles hit-under-miss.  Miss-under-miss to memory-level parallelism of multiple misses in flight also helps, as well as being able to get to a hit after 2 or more cache-miss loads.)

**I think usually for most workloads with different cache geometries and sizes, there won't be significant bias towards more of the misses being easier to hide or not, so you could still say that miss-rate is the only thing that ultimately matters.**

Miss-rate for a cache depends on workload, so you can't say that a lower miss rate on just one workload or trace makes it better on average or for all cases.  e.g. an 8-way associative 16 KiB cache might have a higher hit rate than a 32 KiB 2-way cache on one workload (with a lot of conflict misses for the 2-way cache), but on a different workload where the working set is mostly one contiguous 24KiB array, the 32K 2-way cache might have a higher hit rate.

Comment: Devil's advocate: A cache which biased replacement by criticality ("misses being easier to hide or not") could have a worse miss rate yet provide better performance. Theoretically, in a multi-level cache one L1 cache design might have a higher miss rate but provide an L2 hit rate sufficiently higher to provide improved performance. If "cache subsystem" includes prefetchers, miss latency is not constant, prefetching could remove only some of the latency (if "hardware complexity" is power/area excluding design complexity this seems plausible). MSHR count might be "cache subsystem".

Comment: In the context of multiple cores, criticality might include local misses that can be serviced from another core's cache (i.e., lower miss cost). I also wonder if a cache system could have a higher miss rate but provide lower communication latency between cores potentially increasing performance while having a higher miss rate. (It seems plausible at least that early transfer of ownership to a shared cache could increase the local miss rate but provide better system performance.) Perhaps a cache could sacrifice hit rate for better utilization of the memory interface (contention latency)?

Answer (score 2):

The term "better" is subjective as follows:

1. Hardware cost, in terms of silicon real-estate, meaning that a larger chip is more expensive to produce and thus costs more per chip.  (A larger cache may not even fit on the chip in question.)
2. Hardware cost, in terms of silicon process technology, meaning that a faster cache requires a more advanced chip process, so will increase costs per chip.
3. A miss rate on a given cache is workload specific (e.g. application specific or algorithm specific).  Thus, two different workloads may have different miss rates on each of the caches in question.  So, "better" here may mean across an average workload (or an average across several different workloads), but there's a lot of room for variability.
4. We would have to know the performance of the caches upon hit, and also upon miss — as a more complex cache with a higher hit rate might have longer timings.

In summary, in order to say that lower miss rate is better, we would have to know that all the other factors are equal.  Otherwise, the notion of better needs to be defined, perhaps to include cost/benefit definition.

Comment: They did stipulate that both caches have *roughly the same hardware complexity*.  But yeah, that's important so it bears repeating (as your points 1 and 2)